# error with VHDL CODE FOR FFT

Tags: assembly, encoding

I have a VHDL code for implementing FFT using butterfly. Its 4 input and 8 output.  There are 2 VHDL files one for fft package and the other for the architechture, inside the fft pachage the butterfly is defined using procedure. If I compile both the fft package and the architecture they show no errors. I am trying to change the procedure to function inside the fft package code but when I change it to function and compile the fft package code, it shows no errors. However if I compile the architecture file again it shows errors near the butterfly!
Is there something wrong with my transforming from procedure to function?

The code that works with procedure is as follows:
(fft package code)

```
 library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;


package fft_package is
TYPE complex IS ARRAY(0 TO 1) OF INTEGER;
CONSTANT w0 : complex := (1, 0);  --Pre-computed constants
CONSTANT w1 : complex := (0, -1); --Pre-computed constants

PROCEDURE butterfly (
                     X1 : in complex;
                     X2 : in complex;
                     W  : in complex;
                     Y1 : out complex;
                     Y2 : out complex
                     );
END fft_package;

package body fft_package is

PROCEDURE butterfly (X1 : in complex;
                     X2 : in complex;
                     W : in complex;
                     Y1 : out complex;
                     Y2 : out complex) IS

BEGIN
-- G1 = X1 + W*X2
Y1(0) := X1(0) + ((W(0)*X2(0)) - W(1)*X2(1)); -- G1 real
Y1(1) := X1(1) + ((W(0)*X2(1)) + W(1)*X2(0)); -- G1 imaginary
-- G2 = X1 - W*X2
Y2(0) := X1(0) - ((W(0)*X2(0)) - W(1)*X2(1)); -- G2 real
Y2(1) := X1(1) - ((W(0)*X2(1)) + W(1)*X2(0)); -- G2 imaginary

END butterfly;
end fft_package;

(architecture code)
entity fft_block is
Port ( X1 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
       X2 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
       X3 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
       X4 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
       CLOCK : in STD_LOGIC;
       aY1_R, aY1_I : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
       aY2_R, aY2_I : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
       aY3_R, aY3_I : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
       aY4_R, aY4_I : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end fft_block;

architecture Behavioral of fft_block is
begin

process (CLOCK)
VARIABLE g0_1, g0_2, g0_3, g0_4 : complex;
VARIABLE g1_1, g1_2, g1_3, g1_4 : complex;
VARIABLE g2_1, g2_2, g2_3, g2_4 : complex;

begin

if CLOCK='1' and CLOCK'event then
g0_1(0) := CONV_INTEGER(X1);
g0_1(1) := 0;
g0_2(0) := CONV_INTEGER(X3);
g0_2(1) := 0;
g0_3(0) := CONV_INTEGER(X2);
g0_3(1) := 0;
g0_4(0) := CONV_INTEGER(X4);
g0_4(1) := 0;

--G1
butterfly(g0_1, g0_2, w0, g1_1, g1_2);
butterfly(g0_3, g0_4, w0, g1_3, g1_4);

--G2
butterfly(g1_1, g1_3, w0, g2_1, g2_3);
butterfly(g1_2, g1_4, w1, g2_2, g2_4);
end if;

-- Outputs
aY1_R <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(g2_1(0),aY1_R'length));
aY1_I <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(g2_1(1),aY1_R'length));
aY2_R <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(g2_2(0),aY1_R'length));
aY2_I <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(g2_2(1),aY1_R'length));
aY3_R <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(g2_3(0),aY1_R'length));
aY3_I <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(g2_3(1),aY1_R'length));
aY4_R <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(g2_4(0),aY1_R'length));
aY4_I <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(g2_4(1),aY1_R'length));
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

the previeous code works well but when i change the procedure and uses the function inside the package i get the error
here is my code for the fft package using function:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;


package fft_package is
TYPE complex IS ARRAY(0 TO 1) OF INTEGER;
CONSTANT w0 : complex := (1, 0);  --Pre-computed constants
CONSTANT w1 : complex := (0, -1); --Pre-computed constants

   function butterfly(X1, X2 , W : complex )return complex;


END fft_package;

package body fft_package is

function butterfly ( X1, X2 , W : complex )return complex is
  VARIABLE Y1, Y2  : complex;

BEGIN
-- G1 = X1 + W*X2
G1:Y1(0) := X1(0) + ((W(0)*X2(0)) - W(1)*X2(1)); -- G1 real
Y1(1) := X1(1) + ((W(0)*X2(1)) + W(1)*X2(0)); -- G1 imaginary

-- G2 = X1 - W*X2
Y2(0) := X1(0) - ((W(0)*X2(0)) - W(1)*X2(1)); -- G2 real
Y2(1) := X1(1) - ((W(0)*X2(1)) + W(1)*X2(0)); -- G2 imaginary
 return Y1;
 return Y2;
END butterfly;
end fft_package;
```

Does anybody know why I get errors when I compile the architecture file after changing the procedure to function inside the fft package?

I got the  same four errors and all are near butterfly! Why?

---

As mentioned in the comments below [the answer from Martin]

I got no errors with the previous code when compiling it. But, the testbench is not created as I mentioned in the comments.

Comment: A function can return only one result. Thus `return Y2;` is never reached. Please format the code as described in the help!

Comment: If you need to return 2 values, combine them into a record or array and return that. Or stick with OUT pramaters in a procedure, there's nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your synthesis /  simulation tool seems not to automatically recompile all dependent VHDL files after you manually recompiled the changed VHDL package.
Thus, errors are reported only after you manually recompiled the "architecture file".

You have not shown us the concrete error message, but you cannot simply replace a `procedure` by a `function`. A procedure can have several output parameters (keyword `out`) and the procedure call makes up (a whole) concurrent or sequential statement like in your example:

```
butterfly(g0_1, g0_2, w0, g1_1, g1_2); -- sequential statement in your example
```

A function can have only input parameters and the return value is the only "output". The function call can be part of an expression. For example you can assign the function result to a variable:

```
g1_1 := butterfly_y1(g0_1, g0_2, w0); -- function which calculates Y1
g1_2 := butterfly_y2(g0_1, g0_2, w0); -- function which calculates Y2
```

I have splitted up your procedure here into two functions, one which calculates the `Y1` part and another for `Y2`. Another option would be use to use a record of signals for the result of the function as Brian pointed out.

**EDIT** splitted butterfly functions:

```
function butterfly_y1 ( X1, X2 , W : complex )return complex is
  VARIABLE Y1 : complex;
BEGIN
  -- G1 = X1 + W*X2
  Y1(0) := X1(0) + ((W(0)*X2(0)) - W(1)*X2(1)); -- G1 real
  Y1(1) := X1(1) + ((W(0)*X2(1)) + W(1)*X2(0)); -- G1 imaginary
  return Y1;
END butterfly_y1;

function butterfly_y2 ( X1, X2 , W : complex )return complex is
  VARIABLE Y2 : complex;
BEGIN
  -- G2 = X1 - W*X2
  Y2(0) := X1(0) - ((W(0)*X2(0)) - W(1)*X2(1)); -- G2 real
  Y2(1) := X1(1) - ((W(0)*X2(1)) + W(1)*X2(0)); -- G2 imaginary
  return Y2;
END butterfly_y2;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. i have tried to use the new two functions u mentioned above to declare Y1 and Y2 inside the architecture body but when i compiled the code i got errors indicates that butterfly_y1  and butterfly_2 not declared! can you please provide me with code of the function inside the package and the function call inside the architecture! because i am confused of how to use the function! Thanks

Comment: this is the error i used to see before 

[Error] fft_arch.vhd Compiler type error near butterfly ; expected type  void

Comment: Your posted code of the function is almost fine. Delete the `G1:`. Then duplicate the function, so that, one `returns Y1;` and the other `returns Y2;` only.

Comment: You tried again to return 2 values, but that is not possible (without records). I have appended both functions to my answer.

Comment: hey Martin, i have followed the steps u illustrated before and made 2 function which i will post them to an answer now, no errors found in both the package code nor the architecture, i tried to create testbench file from the arch code and i put the stimulus cases inside it to test my design but when i click on simulator to simulate it with Aldec OEM simulator i see (no test bench configuration found).. the code i used to run before using procedure used to show stimulus of testftt_block .., is there something wrong again with my edit to the code, i will provide the changed i made as an answer!

Comment: I don't know the Aldec OEM simulator. The definitions of the butterfly functions in fft_package are right. But, you still call a procedure `butterfly` in the architecture. This code should not compile. Always recompile all architecture files if you change one package file!

Comment: sorry i forgot to post the modified architecture code, i just edited my answer with the new architecture code which showed no errors, i used butterfly_y1 and butterfly_y2 in the process, if u find nything wrong with my new architecure, please let me know and thank you for your patience :)

Comment: The function calls look good. The output assignments should be moved inside the `if-end` block as well, so that the results are registered with the rising edge of the clock. It would be nice, if you accept and upvote my answer for all this help.